# How to translate these defitions of bipartiteness to each other?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, predicate-logic, axioms, bipartite-graphs

Let $(V,E)$ be a bipartite graph. I'm trying to capture this property and I've come up with two definitions and am surprised/confused that one uses a negation and the other doesn't - still I can't convert the one to the other.

So let $v,w$ be vertices in $V$ and let $X,Y$ denote subsets of $V$ with $X\cap Y=\emptyset$. I'd say bipartite means

"If the vertices $u$ and $v$ are connected, then one is in part $X$ and the other is in part $Y$."

$\exists X,Y.\ \forall u,v.\ [\ \{u,v\}\in E\implies (u\in X\land v\in Y)\lor (v\in X\land u\in Y)\ ]$

as well as

"If the vertices $u$ and $v$ are connected, then the don't belong to the same part."

$\exists X,Y.\ \forall u,v.\ [\ \{u,v\}\in E\implies \neg(u\in X\land v\in X)\land \neg(v\in Y\land u\in Y)\ ]$

I tried to use de Morgans law to change

$\{u,v\}\in E\implies (u\in X\land v\in Y)\lor (v\in X\land u\in Y)$

to

$\{u,v\}\in E\implies \neg(u\in X\land v\in X)\land \neg(v\in Y\land u\in Y)$

but can't get rid or produce the negations. Is there a set theoretical property I have to use, or must I maybe break out further of the $\implies$ conditional. Or did I just write down the axiomatization badly?

Comment: You need the requirement that $X\cup Y=V$ for the second definition, otherwise you can have $u\in X$ and $v\in V\setminus(X\cup Y)$ and $u,v$ connected and still call it bipartite under the second definition.

Comment: And maybe (I haven't really looked into it) you also need $X\cap Y=\emptyset$.

Comment: Definitely need that, @Ragnar, but he already included that condition (Although not in the formal statements.)